# INDIRECT with increasing cell reference A1 A2 A3 etc

Tags: excel, excel-formula

may i know how to enable 
(CELL A1 in SHEET1)

`=INDIRECT('SHEET2.A1')`

to drag through columns and rows accordingly without having to type it out one by one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a cell reference in the `Indirect()` function, which resolves to the value in the referenced cell.  Given Sheet1:

```
ColA
------
This
is
a
test
```

And these values and formulas in Sheet2:

```
ColA    ColB
------  ------
A1      =INDIRECT("Sheet1!"&A1)
A2      =INDIRECT("Sheet1!"&A2)
A3      =INDIRECT("Sheet1!"&A3)
A4      =INDIRECT("Sheet1!"&A4)
```

The values in Sheet2 look like this:

```
ColA    ColB
------  ------
A1      This
A2      is
A3      a
A4      test
```

It is easy to then fill-down (drag fomulas down) that auto-increment the cell references in column A, and the indirect formulas in column B.

Comment: This is an off-sheet question, so you should add the sheet name.

Comment: +1 post update :). You culd avoid hard-coiding the column A values with a formula like `=INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!A"&ROW(A1))` copied down

Comment: So, you placed the `INDIRECT` function in Sheet2:B1?  And Sheet2:A1 has the value `A1` in it?

Answer (score 14):

Sometimes `CELL` function can be useful here, e.g.

`=INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&CELL("address",A1))`

That can be dragged down or across

---

Comment: Simplest answer I've seen thus far.

Comment: Why the single quotes?

Comment: You don't need them if the sheet name is sheet1 but if a sheet name has spaces or is numeric then it needs single quotes around it, so I'm just showing the "generic" method that will work for any sheet name

Comment: Would you happen to know how this solution works if I wanted to cross-reference a sheet name from a cell rather than hard-coding it it? I tried `INDIRECT(A1&CELL("address",A9))` where A1 contains the name of the sheet, but this results in #REF errors.

Answer (score 3):

On second thought, posting my comment to another answer as an answer

**`For copying down`**

You can use
`=INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!A"&ROW(A1))`
to increment directly without a helper column

Note that the `'` is needed around the sheet name to handle situations where the sheet you are referencing is `'Sheet 1'` rather than `Sheet1`

**`For copying across`**
`=INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!A"&COLUMN()-1)`

In Cell B1 will give = `Sheet1A1`
In Cell C1 will give = `Sheet1A2`
etc

Comment: using &ROW(A1) will give me the value of 1 i tried using &COLUMN CHAR +64 something like that but it gives me problems

Comment: @JervisChionh I thought you were dragging down so that would increment as you did do. Are you dragging this accross columns?

Answer (score 0):

an option would be to try `OFFSET`.

> OFFSET(reference, rows, cols, [height], [width])

link to: [microsoft help](http://office.microsoft.com/client/helppreview14.aspx?AssetId=HP010342739&lcid=1033&NS=EXCEL&Version=14&tl=2&CTT=5&origin=HP010342670)

perhaps using `ROWS()`, or even work it out based on values - I've used it to look up info based on formula like `MONTH(Q11)`